# Choosing lmer model for repeated measurements with interactions

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, panel-data, multiple-comparisons

I am modeling the longitudinal data attached below with lmer model. Time_point increases in steps of 6 months. I wish to compare Groups 2, 3 scores to group 1 in time, taking into consideration age at baseline.

```
structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
               13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
                8L, 8L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
                "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"), class = "factor"), 
               Group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
               3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
               "2", "3"), class = "factor"), Age = c(65.7, 65.7, 65.7, 65.7, 
               65.7, 65.7, 65.7, 65.7, 65.7, 65.7, 68.8, 68.8, 68.8, 60.9, 
               60.9, 51, 51, 51, 67.4, 64.1, 75.9, 60.4, 60.4, 60.4, 60.4, 
               67.6, 67.6, 67.6, 67.6, 67.6, 67.6, 67.6, 67.6, 65.3, 65.3, 
               65.3, 65.3, 65.3), Time_point = c(0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 0, 6, 
               12, 18, 24, 0, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 6, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 12, 
               0, 6, 12, 24, 0, 6, 12, 24, 0, 6, 12, 0, 6), Score = c(94, 
               94, 96, 96, 93, 90, 94, 94, 94, 91, 113, 100, 99, 103, 101, 
               82, 79, 80, 94, 114, 73, 105, 105, 99, 99, 93, 94, 91, 87, 
               90, 84, 88, 85, 92, 92, 91, 86, 86)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 
               3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 358L, 
               359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 510L, 511L, 
               512L, 513L, 514L, 515L, 516L, 517L, 518L, 519L, 520L, 521L, 522L),
               class = "data.frame")
```

I am considering the two models:

```
model1<-lmer(Score~(Age+Time_point)*Group+(1|Subject), REML = F,
          data=dat,control = lmerControl(optimizer ="Nelder_Mead"))

model2<-lmer(Score~Age*Time_point*Group+(1|Subject), REML = F,
          data=dat,control = lmerControl(optimizer ="Nelder_Mead"))
``
note: I cannot add (1+Time_point|Subject) or (Time_point|Subject) due to singularity

Which model would be better to show changes in score over time for the groups compared to group 1? how should I interpert and display the lmer output?
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the excellent response of @RobertLong, just a couple of extra points:

- Given the small sample size, it would be best to use the REML approach because it provides less biased estimates in this case.
- Perhaps the motivation to use `lmer(..., REML = FALSE)` is to do a likelihood ratio test, but, again because of the sample size, it would be best to use an F-test as provided by the **lmerTest** package.
- Regarding adding random slopes, you could check whether assuming a diagonal covariance matric for the random effects leads to a model the converges and produces sensible results. I.e., use `(Time_point || Subject)`.

Comment: Good points Dimitris. I already tried the diagonal VCV matrix but it still produces a singular fit (zero variation in the random slopes).

Comment: Dimitris, @RobertLong thank you for your comments. My original dataset is larger, I will test your suggestions on it

Comment: ***By using F-test do you mean using `anova`? In that case, I don't see any comparisons between the groups

Answer (score 3):

> note: I cannot add (1+Time_point|Subject) or (Time_point|Subject) due to singularity

First note that `(1+Time_point|Subject)` and `(Time_point|Subject)` are exactly the same.

Second it is not surprising that the addition of random slopes leads to a singular fit - you have only 38 observations and 15 groups. A slightly more Parsimonious model is to specify no correlation between the random slopes and the intercepts using the `||` notation as per @DimitrisRizopoulos suggestion, but this also results in a singular fit.

> Which model would be better to show changes in score over time for the groups compared to group 1? how should I interpert and display the lmer output?

Since your research question concerns the *changes in score over time for the groups* then you would want to fit the model:

```
model3 <- lmer(Score ~ Age + Time_point*Group + (1|Subject), REML = F,
      data = dat,control = lmerControl(optimizer ="Nelder_Mead"))

summary(model3)

    Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)       107.01810   33.15382   3.228
Age                -0.25078    0.49352  -0.508
Time_point         -0.19094    0.05750  -3.321
Group2              9.82282    6.54333   1.501
Group3              3.20809    6.50194   0.493
Time_point:Group2   0.18951    0.08029   2.360
Time_point:Group3   0.13377    0.11964   1.118
```

this tells us:

- There is an expected score of 107 for a subject of age 0 at time 0 for group 1
- There is a linear association (slope) of -0.25 between Score and Age with the other variables held constant -
- There is a linear association (slope) of -0.19 between Score and Time_Point with Age held constant, for group 1
- There is a difference of 9.8 in Score between Group1 and Group 2 with Age held constant at time point 0
- There is a difference of 3.2 in Score between Group1 and Group 3 with Age held constant at time point 0
- There is a differece of 0.19 in the slope of time point between group 1 and group 2, with Age held constant
- There is a differece of 0.14 in the slope of time point between group 1 and group 3, with Age held constant.

You could centre the Age variable to improve interpretability of the intercept but it won't change the overall interpretation.

Note that in the model output most standard errors are very large compared to the corresponding estimates, meaning that that if those coefficients were actually zero, the probability of obtaining these, or more extreme, results again is quite high.  This could be due to several things:

- the sample size is too small to detect an "effect"
- the variables measured have very little associations with the outcome
- other (non measured) variables are much more important.
- there is actually no difference between the groups
- large measurement error

It is also worth noting that there the estimate for the random intercepts variance is quite high:

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 93.408   9.665   
 Residual              2.384   1.544
```

which indicates that there is a lot of variation in score at the `Subject` level. This could mean that you may need to measure other subject-specific variables other than age.